# Android: Circular Google Map fragment

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps

I am using Google Map fragment in my Android app. But, I need to be circular in shape like below. How can I implement it?

[image: Circular Map Fragment]

Map Fragment code snippet is:

```
<fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            />
```

Comment: I've done it as a sqaure before, I wrapped it with a square frame layout. So in your case you should make a circular frame layout which extends framelayout and wrap the fragment with it.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't need the map to be interactive (no swiping, zooming, etc.), then you could use the Google Static Maps API which gives you an image of the requested map: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/

Then you could put that image inside and ImageView, and apply a circular mask on it (you can find lot's of examples for that on StackOverflow)