# Show Map within a Circle/Round Layout

Tags: java, android

I have a Requirement Like this(screenshot below), I found no particular solution to build this layout in the stack overflow. Can anyone help me to build this layout

The map will be inside circled/rounded view and the red border will work as a timer, as time reduce, red border will be reduce as well.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: Circular Google Map fragment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33385970/android-circular-google-map-fragment)

Comment: @RoShanShan I go the question that you marked, but not found any satisfactory answer, and also if you notice my screenshot, you will find the timer section, which is no way similar to the other question, so I have not  found any way of duplication? If you have any solution to the above, please share.

Answer (score 2):

> Show map as a circle

I have a ... trick solution for you :))

[image]

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="your map"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="@drawable/bg"
            android:gravity="center">

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

And the magic is the image `bg` .The color around must be the same color of your background

[image]

> Red border will work as a timer, as time reduce, red border

You can use this [lib](https://github.com/lzyzsd/CircleProgress) to show your circle progress bar

Comment: Thanks Mate,  Your solution does help me. Shortly I provide the entire code.  +1

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the map fragment inside a FrameLayout along with an ImageView. The Imageview would display a rounded rectangle on top of the map fragment.

```
   <FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/circle" />
</FrameLayout>
```

and a circle shape can be;

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:shape="oval">
        <gradient
            android:angle=""
            android:endColor=""
            android:startColor=""/>
    </shape>
```